# How to make FFMPEG video grayscale?

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

In my program I am using the subprocess Python module in my script to call on FFMPEG to turn a sequence of images into a video (grayscale). It works and a video is created, but upon further inspection I see that the video itself has encoded the different intensities incorrectly.

Here is my code:

```
                subprocess.call(['/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg', '-framerate', \
                             framerate, '-f', 'image2','-pattern_type', \
                             'glob', '-i', self.directory + '/orbit_*.png', \
                             '-r', '10', '-s', '620x380', '-flags', 'gray', self.directory + 
                             ".avi"])
```

Here is a link to the video that's created: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxt1siua2KQma0JaMVBMcE9TOEE

If you'll look at the scale bar on the right in the video, which normally looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b39Kq.png)
in color, you'll see that the same color shows up twice on the scale bar. I think it's because FFMPEG is reading colors with the same intensities (for example, yellow and blue) the same way and therefore when the photo is encoded into grayscale it looks like this.

What can I do? Is this a matter of changing the "-flags", "gray" parameters of my subprocess call?

Comment: Your `drive.google.com` link is private. Make it public (settings) otherwise no one can see your issue.

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks for the note!

Comment: @VC.One, have you gotten a chance to take a look at this? Your help would be very appreciated!